# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'PositiveSmallIntgerField'

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in django I started facing this issue while running the manage.py runserver

this is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models her
class Product(models.Model):
Product_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
Name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
Price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
Quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntgerField(default=1)
Reviews = models.TextField()

def _str_(self):
   return self.Name

class Buyer(models.Model):
Buyer_ID = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
Name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
DOB = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
Address = models.CharField(max_length=264)
Sex = models.CharField(max_length=6)
Reviews = models.TextField()
Product_ID = models.ForeignKey(Product)

def _str_(self):
   return self.Name

class Seller(models.Model):
Seller_ID = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
Name = models.CharField(max_legth=264)
Contact = model.IntegerField()
Product_ID = models.ForeignKey(Product)

def _str_(self):
   return self.Name

class Order(models.Model):
Order_ID = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
DateOfDelivery = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
Buyer_ID = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)
Product_ID = models.ForeignKey(Product)

def _str_(self):
   return self.Product.Name

class Admin(models.Model):
Admin_ID = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
Name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
Contact = models.IntegerField()
Product_ID = models.ForeignKey(Product)
Seller_ID = models.ForeignKey(Seller)
Buyer_ID = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)

def _str_(self):
   return self.Name
```

The error i get is: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'CharField'.
I have already crossed check any other settings or files to be imported but everything is in place

Comment: Have you spelled it correctly? `PositiveSmallIntegerField`.You are missing one `e` in `integer`.

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Write Integer not Intger.

Comment: Thx dude, i didn't notice it at all.

Comment: But what about the CharField error?

Comment: Are you sure it is showing `..no attribute CharField`? I guess it will be showing no attribute `Charfield`. Do check your model once, find the misspelling.